# Create event with submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, submit

I need some help on coding my project. Can you please help me to finish my project. I need to create `.click` event to anchor, the code will be as follows:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  if ($("input:first").val() == "something") { 
    // anchor tag should be clicked and input should find submitted target.
  }
}
```

Shortly I want to create search form which creates click event and finds entered target.

Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Comment: what does this "// anchor tag should be clicked and input should find submitted target." mean??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you’re trying to jump to an anchor in the page based on what’s entered in the form.

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('input:first', this).val() == 'something') {
    // anchor tag should be clicked and input should find submitted target.
    window.location.hash = 'example-hash';
  }
)};
```

If there are multiple options, you could use `switch`:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  var val = $('input:first', this).val(),
      hash;
  e.preventDefault();
  switch (val) {
    case 'foo':
      hash = 'some-hash';
      break;
    case 'bar':
      hash = 'some-other-hash';
      break;
    default:
      hash = 'default-hash';
      break;
  }
  window.location.hash = hash;
)};
```

Comment: @Avaz: I’m not sure what you mean. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to add to this code one more function, the input should jump to an anchor and make it (anchor I mean) click

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to override the default submit-behavior and click an anchor instead:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  if ($("input:first").val() == "something") { 
       $("#anchorelementId").trigger('click');
       e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the submit-behavior from your form.
  }
}
```